# Routing OpenAI API requests from an Android app thorough a backend server

Tags: android, kotlin, backend, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm just starting to learn about mobile development, backend setup etc. so apologies if any of this is very basic but I’m not sure how to figure this out myself.

I’m trying to create an Android app in Kotlin (with Android Studio Flamingo) that uses one of OpenAI’s language models. OpenAI’s [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/authentication), obviously, says that for production apps, all API calls should be routed through a backend server (where, I guess, the key can be set as an environment variable) to avoid exposing the API  key in the app’s code. I’m planning to use one of the pre-build backend services such AWS, Back4App or Firebase to store the necessary data for my app. However I’m not sure how to use those, if it is even possible, to route API requests from the app to OpenAI - that is what scripts would I have to run on the server, how to modify the code making the request in the app etc.

I was planning to use the open source OpenAI Kotlin library from here for the code that would run inside the app: https://github.com/Aallam/openai-kotlin

I realise that this could involve a lot of work so I was wondering if someone could at least point me towards some resources where I could learn more about this.

Comment: Firebase functions is what I use. OpenAI's API for node.js gives you a huge chunk of what you need or you can use axios to use curl calls. The only hard part was streaming but I ultimately got it working. You don't need anything other than Firebase in the Kotlin/Client-side.

Comment: If you just need a server to call an API, it would be more practical to spin up your own. There are tons of languages to choose from so it's up to you what you want to use. One of the most beginner friendly is Python, so give that a shot I guess.

Comment: You can use Back4app to meet your needs as well. With cloud code and express, you can create specific routes to call this function through a simple URL.

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum that gives me some direction.

Comment: @Charles I see thanks.